# How do you check/match a "string" to "sentence" starting at word number "wordNum" of "sentence"

Tags: c++

This is a class function returns a true value if string `str` matches the string `sentence` starting at word number `wordNum` of `sentence`. Rules are:

1. match is case insensitive
2. the end of `str` must not fall in the middle of a word in "sentence"
3. the word number in `wordNum` is a value starting at 1, so that 1 refers to the first word, and vice versa. If `wordNum` is less than 0 or greater than the number in `sentence`, no match.

Also what if the start of `sentence` is a whitespace what code should it be?

this is the code that I have worked on

```cpp
int Directive::words(const char* sentence) { // this function counts the number of words
    int wordCount = 0;
    int letterCount = 0;

    while (*sentence) {
        if (isspace(*sentence) || *sentence == '.' || *sentence == ',' || *sentence == '!') {
            if (letterCount)
                wordCount++;
            letterCount = 0;
        }
        else
            letterCount++;
        sentence++;
    }

    if (letterCount)
        wordCount++;

    return wordCount;
}

int Directive::matchDirective(const char* str, const char* sentence, int wordNum) {
    int wordCount = words(sentence);
    int strLength = strlen(str);

    char strTemp[100];
    char sentenceTemp[100];

    strcpy(strTemp, str);
    strcpy(sentenceTemp, sentence);

    if (wordNum > wordCount) {
        return false;
    }

    char* temp;

    temp = strstr(sentenceTemp, strTemp);

    if (temp != NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I recommend writing it up using `std::string`, and then convert to `char` arrays as necessary.

Comment: `strstr` is the right place to start, but remember you want a case-insensitive compare. The easiest way to do that is to convert `str` and `sentence` to all upper or lower case. A couple loops and `tolower` will fix that up quickly. So would `std::transform`, but if that's on the table you probably wouldn't be using `char` arrays.

Comment: You also need to start the compare at a particular word. That means you'll want a function to find and count words. I don't think there is one built in, so you'll have to write your own. Something like a `const char * find_position(const char* sentence, int wordNum))` that returns a pointer to the found start word should help.

Comment: Consider solving the problem with [std::regex_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator)

Comment: An entire assignment is usually too broad for a Stack Overflow question. I'd advise you focus your question on a smaller piece. For example, can you write a function that returns a true value if string `str` matches the string `sentence` starting at the first word, case-sensitively? (This would include the check for not ending in the middle of a word.) Can you add in case-insensitivity? Can you start at an arbitrary word? Which piece is giving you trouble? Describe the symptoms.